# Простой пример парсера htmp страницы

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ

Прошу простой пример парсера htmp, желательно стардарнными средствами. Гуглил-гуглил, нашел мало чего понятного. Так что, пожалуйста "тыкните носом" в ссыль на эту тему, либо дайте исходничек.

Comment: Чет про стандартные средства сказал зря...

Comment: читаю http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/121815/

Comment: в принципе, в этой статье есть предостаточно ссылок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример парсера, используются библиотеки Grab и PyQuery

```
from grab import Grab
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import re

NEWS_COUNT = 10
def loadPage(url):
    g = Grab()
    g.setup(timeout = 15, connect_timeout = 10)
    g.go(url)
    response = str(g.response.body)
    return response

def readEchoNews():
    siteUrl = "http://echo.msk.ru"
    url = siteUrl+"/news/"
    page = loadPage(url)
    if page:
        result = []
        d = pq(page)
        newsBlock = d("dl.frame.newsList.newsInside ul.list").children()
        newsElements = []
        for i in range(NEWS_COUNT): newsElements.append(newsBlock.eq(i))
        for one in newsElements:
            #print one.text()
            a = one.find("a.name")
            title = a.text().strip()
            href = a.attr("href")
            num = href.replace("/news/", "").replace("-echo.html", "")
            descr = one.find("div.descr").text().strip().replace("...", ".")
            text = u"%s. %s"%(title, descr)
            text = ' '.join(re.findall(u"[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\,\.]+", text))
            result.append({'num': num, 'href': siteUrl+href, 'text': text})
        return result
    else:
        return False
```